# Is there a online building server for developing Android Applications

Tags: android

I am looking for a online building server(Hudson or jenkins) for Android application development. I already have my code on the Github. Can anyone help me? Thanks very much!

Comment: Either of those will work (Given that they're the same thing, basically).

Comment: Sorry, I mean a hosted solution using Hudson or Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a build server yourself, install it on your machine and set it up to pull and build your project. If you want at a hosted solution, look at [CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com/) and the services they offer.

Comment: Hi I want a hosted solution. Thank you!